# json_decode - Decoding standard JSON code not working

Tags: php, json, wordpress

The problem occurs in wordpress and I simply can't figure out what is wrong. I have a string. var_dump returns this:

```
string(300) "{\"7\":{\"text\":\"sdf\",\"direction\":\"horizontal\",\"font\":\"Oswald\",\"x\":\"30\",\"y\":\"37\",\"width\":\"40\",\"height\":\"11.43\",\"image\":0},\"8\":{\"text\":\"34\",\"direction\":\"horizontal\",\"font\":\"Oxygen\",\"x\":\"30\",\"y\":\"44\",\"width\":\"40\",\"height\":\"41.29\",\"image\":0}}"
```

I tried:

```
json_decode($string);
json_decode(stripslashes($string));
json_decode(str_replace('\\', '', $string);
```

Neither works. I tried everything possible to enable error reporting in wordpres (newest version), but, for some reason, wordpress developers thought that they must do everything for developers not to see errors. So I can't see what the error is.

Please, help.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with last 2 lines you pasted. Try doing the functions separately, and var_dump the string after the stripslashes and str_replace

Comment: Can you use `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()`.

Comment: Yes it works fine when I copy/paste the string from var_dump output, but it doesn't for the variable itself. The result for both last lines of my code is quite predictable - the same thing but without slashes

Comment: var_export() outputs '{\\"7\\":{\\"text\\":\\"sdf\\",\\"direction\\":\\"horizontal\\",\\"font\\":\\"Oswald\\",\\"x\\":\\"30\\",\\"y\\":\\"37\\",\\"width\\":\\"40\\",\\"height\\":\\"11.43\\",\\"image\\":0},\\"8\\":{\\"text\\":\\"34\\",\\"direction\\":\\"horizontal\\",\\"font\\":\\"Oxygen\\",\\"x\\":\\"30\\",\\"y\\":\\"44\\",\\"width\\":\\"40\\",\\"height\\":\\"41.29\\",\\"image\\":0}}'

Comment: The weirdest thing is that var_dump(json_decode($string)); outputs NULL, not an error

Comment: All 3 forms work with the string you provide

Comment: It works when I output the string. 

Tried the last_json_error_msg - returns Syntax error

Comment: Then I think you are going to have to show us the real code, because something is having an effect that we cannot see currently

Comment: @Riggs You're looking at a `var_dump`. That means the string actually contains backslashes. If you take that and paste it into code, you get a *string literal*, whose backslashes will be interpreted. The final string *won't* contain backslashes. Look at the `var_export` version posted above for a version that *can* be used as a string literal and preserves its meaning.

Comment: @deceze Ahhhhhhhhhh I see. Now only 2 and 3 work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was the utf-8 BOM in the beginning of the variable. The JSON string was generated by JSON.stringify - maybe this was the problem. Maybe some wordpress thingy, maybe javascript problem

```
json_decode(stripslashes(str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF",'',$details))))
```

Comment: You should perhaps question where exactly you get that string from, and whether there are Wordpress functions that you're supposed to use to deal with this correctly, rather than reverse-engineering whatever it is that Wordpress does there. And/or fix how Wordpress is creating that string.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$str= "{\"7\":{\"text\":\"sdf\",\"direction\":\"horizontal\",\"font\":\"Oswald\",\"x\":\"30\",\"y\":\"37\",\"width\":\"40\",\"height\":\"11.43\",\"image\":0},\"8\":{\"text\":\"34\",\"direction\":\"horizontal\",\"font\":\"Oxygen\",\"x\":\"30\",\"y\":\"44\",\"width\":\"40\",\"height\":\"41.29\",\"image\":0}}";
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($str));

?>
```

Output:-

stdClass Object
(
    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => sdf
            [direction] => horizontal
            [font] => Oswald
            [x] => 30
            [y] => 37
            [width] => 40
            [height] => 11.43
            [image] => 0
        )

```
[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [text] => 34
        [direction] => horizontal
        [font] => Oxygen
        [x] => 30
        [y] => 44
        [width] => 40
        [height] => 41.29
        [image] => 0
    )
```

)

Comment: again. It works when I copy the string. But it doesn't work with the provided by wordpress variable